# Birt Page Break (Grid + Group Header)

Tags: birt, page-break

I need to find the way to configure a real page Break for a grid:
When I set the pageBreak property for a grid now this have effect only to grid row and not count the group header row.

Anyone know if this is possible to set a property that takes into consideration both?

PS: I use birt report designer 4.3.1

Comment: Why would you like to do this at all? For PDF output, the emitter can handle page breaking, e.g. you could set a page break interval of 10000. This works as well with the Word emitter. And for non-page-oriented output like HTML, I don't see why this could be important.

Comment: I would like to do this because I have an application that embedded Birt report viewer and i want the same page and the same pageBreak interval in HTML output and PDF/Word Output.

Comment: This only makes sense if the detail and header rows all have the same height. BIRT does not support this directly. You could try to do the grouping yourself with advanced SQL features.

Comment: Yes, all the detail/header/group rows have the same height. I'm still looking for a solution for this problem. Is really possible that there is no configuration/script for have this result with Birt?

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box solution. As I said, you would have to emulate this yourself.